# Why does Eclipse fail on this scanf() command when the Command Prompt executes it fine?

Tags: c, eclipse

I'm new to C. Here's my code:

```
/* Using scanf() */
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int iDec1, iDec2, iDec3;
    printf("Enter three decimals:\n");
    scanf("%d,%d,%d", &iDec1, &iDec2, &iDec3);
    printf("Your decimals are %d, %d and %d.", iDec1, iDec2, iDec3);
    return 0;
}
```

It works in the Command Prompt, but when I run it through Eclipse it doesn't do anything. After hitting stop, this appears in the Console output:

> > Enter three decimals
> >
> > Your decimals are 3, 2147344384 and 2147344384.

What the...? How come it works fine outside Eclipse but not inside Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fflush(stdout);` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

So, this [thread](http://www.coderanch.com/t/104439/IDEs-Version-Control-other-tools/Eclipse-console-input) might help you out. Yes, it's for Java, not C, but the last post on this thread outlines how to get input to work in eclipse console.  This may just come down to how you run your program.

If the info in the link doesn't help, please post the steps you take to execute your program (which menu options you use etc.  Also post eclipse version).  I'll try to replicate.

Comment: The thing is... according to my code, the printf() command should be executed before the scanf() command. I don't see that printf() command on the screen before the program freezes, which not how I wrote the code.

Answer (score -1):

you can use fflush(stdout); after the print cmd so it will refresh and u will get your input screen.

Comment: Redundant (repetitive) answer on old question.  The OP figured it out 12+ years ago!